# Sodium crypto_aead_aes256gcm_encrypt ciphertext length > plaintext length

Tags: aes, gcm, libsodium

Using the [crypto_aead_aes256gcm functions](https://download.libsodium.org/doc/secret-key_cryptography/aes-256-gcm.html) from Sodium produces a ciphertext of "at most mlen (plaintext length) + crypto_aead_aes256gcm_ABYTES bytes (16 bytes) are put into c (ciphertext), and the actual number of bytes is stored into clen if clen is not a NULL pointer. The phrase "at most" is deceiving because, in testing, ciphertext length is always plaintext length + 16 bytes. **Why is this the case if in the** [specifications for GCM](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-38D/SP-800-38D.pdf) **the output is a ciphertext**, denoted C, **whose bit length is the same as that of the plaintext** (5.2.1.2).

I was going to attempt to read/write files using this, so would I just read 32 bytes at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result you are getting is the cipher text (the encrypted data) plus 16 bytes of authentication data. The authentication data (mentioned directly below the ciphertext in the resource you cited) ensures that the ciphertext cannot be changed without the change being detected, and is the (most important) thing that distinguishes GCM from regular CTR-Mode.

The authentication data is the same length, no matter how much data you encrypt. So, if you encrypt 1024 bytes, you will still only get 16 bytes of authentication data. This means that you will only have to plan for those extra 16 bytes once and can read / write all remaining data as usual, although it would probably be a good idea to check some open source projects using the same library and cryptography and see how they are doing it, just to be sure you're not making any mistakes (at least that's what I usually do).

Edit: Also note that implementation questions are better suited for Stackoverflow, as the Crypto Stackexchange mostly deals with the *concepts* and not the *implementations* of cryptography.

Comment: Even specifying Null auth data with 0 length gives me mlen + abytes. So the authenticated data is just somewhere in the library's implementation?

Comment: The auth data you are talking about is [Additional Authenticated Data (AAD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption), which is optional. GCM will always give you an authentication *tag*, no matter if you specify AAD. AAD is used to authenticate data that is not contained in the plain text, for example a file name or similar things.

Comment: If you want plaintext_length == ciphertext_length, you cannot use GCM and have to use something like CTR mode. However, you should [never use encryption without authentication](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/2206/20775).

Comment: Ahh I see. I was under the impression AAD was just regular AD. So for each round of encryption (say 16 bytes), I'll get 32 (16 plain + 16 AD) back each time? Doubling file size doesn't sound so appealing if it means verifying the data is correct.

Comment: No, you will only get the authentication data once per encryption. So, if you encrypt 512 KB of data, you will get 512 KB of ciphertext + 16 byte of authentication data.

Comment: (If you manually split the file into chunks of 16 byte and encrypt them separately, THEN you will double the file size. However, there's no good reason to do this instead of encrypting the whole file at once)

Comment: I guess I'll just look at other implementations.  If I were to read in 16 bytes, encrypt, and output (fwrite ctext, ctext length), it would double the file size because each encryption produces 16 bytes of AD, unless of course sodium can take an input of arbitrary size. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The API of sodium looks like it will take arbitrary lengths of plaintext using the MESSAGE and MESSAGE_LEN parameters, so you should be good. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted to clean up the list of unanswered questions :)

Comment: I'll test arbitrary lengths later. Already marked as accepted ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37288/discussion-between-user10984587-and-malexmave).